# Get last element of type string in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

Suppose I have a list of different types:

i.e.

```
[7, 'string 1', 'string 2', [a, b c], 'string 3', 0, (1, 2, 3)]
```

Is there a Pythonic way to return 'string 3' ?

Comment: So based on what kind of condition you want that?

Comment: @Kasra, the condition is in the title. "last element of type string".

Comment: Hint: Use `next()` with `reversed()` and a generator expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a given type, you can use several kinds of comprehensions to get what you need.

```
[el for el in lst if isinstance(el, given_type)][-1]
# Gives the last element if there is one, else IndexError
```

or

```
next((el for el in reversed(lst) if isinstance(el, given_type)), None)
# Gives the last element if there is one, else None
```

If this is something you're doing often enough, you can factor it into a function:

```
def get_last_of_type(type_, iterable):
    for el in reversed(iterable):
        if isinstance(el, type_):
            return el
    return None
```

Comment: The `next()` version avoids copying the list, which may have performance implications under certain circumstances.  However, in many cases, this is a micro-optimization.  Always profile first.

Comment: @Kevin right. More importantly it avoids throwing `IndexError`s that should really be `None`s. If I'm asking for the last string in a list, and there are no strings in the list, I expect my answer to be `None` not to interrupt my program flow! :)

Comment: @Adam: Not necessarily.  If I expect a string to be there, and it isn't, my program has a bug and it should stop running now so it doesn't corrupt any important data.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think the easiest way would be to grab the last element of a filtered list.

```
filter(lambda t: type(t) is type(''), your_list)[-1]
```

or

```
[el for el in your_list if type(el) is type('')][-1]
```

Comment: It's customary to compare types with `is` rather than with `==`, since a metaclass can override the latter.

Comment: Also, `type('')` is just `str` in both 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @Kevin sure, but that isn't didactic. OP may want to know an abstract way to match types without having to hard-code the type name.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) solution:

```
>>> l = [7, 'string 1', 'string 2', 8, 'string 3', 0, (1, 2, 3)]
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str), reversed(l)), None)
'string 3'
```

In case you can't use imports for whatever reason, the polyfill for [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) is as follows:

```
def dropwhile(predicate, iterable):
    # dropwhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) --> 6 4 1
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    for x in iterable:
        if not predicate(x):
            yield x
            break
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
lst = [7, 'string 1', 'string 2', [a, b c], 'string 3', 0, (1, 2, 3)]
filtered_string = [ x for x in lst if type(x) is str]
```

now you can get any index of it
for last index

```
filtered_string[-1]
```